# loglikelihood decrease very slightly in EM algorithm

Tags: expectation-maximization, mixture-distribution

I am working with a very large and complicated function. I am using EM algorithm to estimate the model parameters. The EM works very well. However, after 27 iteration I see that the values of the loglikelihood function decreases very slightly (from 154.2335 to 154.2122). I do not understand why that is happen. Then, it works just nice and the function increases again. Does anyone have experience of this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: The R code does not include the EM step, hence makes it hard to spot an issue. By virtue of the Jensen inequality, a proper EM step cannot decrease the likelihood value. This may be due to rounding errors.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you so  much for your comment. I updated my question and include the main idea of my code.

Comment: If you use numerical optimisation you will have rounding and approximations of all sorts, not much of a surprise then.

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks so much. I really appreciate your help. how can I fix it. Can, I take the last values of EM  before it decrease. I mean, if it is decrease, then, stop algorithm as it is converge.

Comment: If you keep track of the likelihood values along iterations, you do not need to stop early, the output being the argument of the largest value found across iterations.

Comment: I think I got part of my problem which is in my code. Thanks again.